# In SSIS how do I compare 2 column names from a join and if they are different update the row in the destination table and insert a new row?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

I have 2 tables:

Table 1: DimBusiness
Column: BusUnitId
Column: BusUnitName
Column: RowIsCurrent (can be 0 or 1)

Table 2: Entity
Column: EntityId
Column: Name

The join is on DimBusiness.BusUnitID = Entity.EntityId

The purpose is to sunset records which have 'expired'

What needs to happen is to select the records in the join where DimBusiness.BusUnitName != Entity.Name

Update the old row in DimBusiness to have RowIsCurrent = 0
Insert a new row in DimBusiness with the new BusUnitName and RowIsCurrent = 1

I've searched on the web and find things which are close.  Right now I basically have done a lookup which has joined the 2 tables but am uncertain what to do next.  I think where I am not seeing the solution is how to do the Update AND then do the Insert.

To clarify - I am looking for the best way to do this using SSIS.

Comment: To do an update and insert you need to have two separate `UPDATE` and `INSERT` statements. I suggest you load all identified sunset records into a table variable, then do the  two seperate `UPDATE` and `INSERT` statements based off that table variable, maybe all in transaction.

Comment: So... first google `T-SQL table variable` on how to define a table variable. Then use `INSERT INTO @MyTableVariable (column1,column2) SELECT column1,column2 FROM MySunsetQuery` to save the list of records to it.

Comment: Do you know how it would be done using SSIS?  That's really where I am trying to go because I want to avoid creating custom t-sql for every situation like this if it's possible to do using the SSIS constructs.  Talend ETL for example allows you to specify a condition on a column (i.e. on the join, if the name value is different do an update and insert) and create an update and insert based on that condition.  I'm not seeing the way to do it in SSIS but I'd imagine it's possible.

Comment: It is possible to do it inside SSIS but personally I don't recommend it because it can only do row by row updates. There is a (in my optinion) _terrible_ SSIS component called the "slowly changing dimension" component that does all of what you want, although it is difficult to maintain and does not scale (due to row by row lookups and row by row updates). https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/karang/2010/09/29/slowly-changing-dimension-using-ssis/

Comment: BTW... custom T-SQL or custom SSIS - pick your poison. It's all custom.

Comment: I did end up using your recommendation to do this in T-SQL.  I talked to another guy today who used the slowly changing dimension for this kind of thing also, but in Talend.  He confirmed your aversion to doing it using a slowly changing dimension, especially in SSIS for performance reasons.  This table is relatively small so I could probably get away with it but chose to do it in T-SQL.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use an *outer* join and put the name condition in the *join* condition, *not* the `where` clause (which makes it an inner join which would discard the rows you're seeking):

```
select ...
from DimBusiness
left join Entity on DimBusiness.BusUnitID = Entity.EntityId
    and DimBusiness.BusUnitName != Entity.Name
```

This will find all `DimBusiness` rows that have a different name from the corresponding `Entity` *or* have no corresponding `Entity`.

It's not clear from your question whether you want the opposite - ie `Entity` rows without a corresponding `DimBusiness`. If that's the case, interchange the two tables in the query.

Comment: I want all rows from DimBusiness that have the same BusUnitId/EntityId but a different BusUnitName/Name.  I actually want an inner join only for this use case.  My question is more around how to do this in SSIS.